# Select + count en una sola consulta de Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

estoy usando  Oracle Versión 18.3.0.277 con windows 10. Tenía una consulta SQL del siguiente tipo:

```
 SELECT
  ped.n_pedido,
  ped.valor,
  op.n_operacion
  from pedido ped join operacion op on ped.id_operacion = op.id
 group by ped.n_pedido,ped.valor, op.n_operacion;
```

Quería saber si se podría modificar la consulta anterior añadiendo algo parecido a

```
sum (ped.valor),
count(*),
```

De modo que sacara en un campo la suma total y en el otro el total de registros (filas encontradas); algo parecido a lo siguiente que sin embargo lo he probado y `sum (ped.valor)` saca lo mismo que `ped.valor` y `count(*)` saca los registros de cada fila.
Ejemplo mi prueba

```
SELECT            
  sum (ped.valor),
  count(*),
  ped.n_pedido,
  ped.valor,
  op.n_operacion
  from pedido ped join operacion op on ped.id_operacion = op.id
 group by ped.n_pedido,ped.valor, op.n_operacion;
```

Comment: No me queda claro lo que quieres lograr, podrías incluir un pequeño conjunto de datos de entrada y la salida que esperas obtener con ellos? Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si la respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás agrupando por cada pedido, valor y operación, por eso no te funciona:

```
SELECT            
  sum (ped.valor),
  count(*),
  ped.n_pedido,
  ped.valor,
  op.n_operacion
  from pedido ped join operacion op on ped.id_operacion = op.id;
```

No agrupes, calcula directamente los totales y obtendrás lo que buscas.

Verás, las consultas de totales o de agregación pueden realizar cálculos `SUM`, `AVG`, `COUNT`, `MAX` ó `MIN` con más de un registro. El `GROUP BY` lo añadimos únicamente para hacer diferentes montones de registros, como si de una baraja de naipes se tratara. Si no haces grupos, trabajas con la baraja completa y la función de agregación la realizas sobre todos los registros de la tabla.